# How to store and update multiple data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables in my database: role's table and role membership's table

role's table

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('RoleName');
        $table->boolean('IsAllCategory')->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->boolean('IsUserCanLogin')->nullable()->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

role membership's table

```
Schema::create('role_memberships', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->string('MembershipName');
        $table->text('MembershipValue');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have a row data in my role's table with RoleName = 'Admin', then I set the membership.. everytime I store role membership data into database, it will store as two rows with same role_id..
This is my controller of Role membership

```
public function show($id)
{
    $role = Role::findOrFail($id);
    $postAdMaxImage = DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $role->id)->where('MembershipName' , 'PostAdMaxImage')->first();
    $postAdExpiredDay = DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->where('MembershipName' , 'PostAdExpiredDay')->first();
    return view('pages/back-end/forms/role/membership')->with('role', $role)
                                                       ->with('postAdMaxImage', $postAdMaxImage)
                                                       ->with('postAdExpiredDay', $postAdExpiredDay);
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $role = Role::findOrFail($id);
    $membership = [
        ['role_id' => $id, 'MembershipName' => 'PostAdMaxImage', 'MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdMaxImage ? $request->PostAdMaxImage : ''],
        ['role_id' => $id, 'MembershipName' => 'PostAdExpiredDay', 'MembershipValue' => $request->PostAdExpiredDay ? $request->PostAdExpiredDay : '']
    ];
    DB::table('role_memberships')->insert($membership);

    return response()->json(array($role, $membership));
}
```

The first problem is in show function.. I can not use first().. I want to get the data to show it into my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Membership</label><br>
      <label>Maximum Gambar untuk Iklan</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" name="PostAdMaxImage" class="form-control" value="{{$postAdMaxImage->MembershipValue}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0 !important">
          <h5>Gambar</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Masa Berlaku Iklan</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" name="PostAdExpiredDay" class="form-control" value="{{$postAdExpiredDay->MembershipValue}}>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0 !important">
          <h5>Hari</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The second problem is, when I want to edit the membership.. It will store as new two rows, not update the last two rows

Comment: what do you mean by **I can not use first()**

Comment: in the second problem your update is in fact a create function , you need to update the field not insert new ones

Comment: @madalinivascu in my show function().. I try to use first() to get single data.. but it shows error `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

Comment: try using select `$postAdMaxImage = DB::table('role_memberships')->select('MembershipValue')->where('role_id', $role->id)->where('MembershipName' , 'PostAdMaxImage')->first();`

Comment: @madalinivascu in the second problem, I am confused how to check the membership ID, because there has two same ID, How can I know if I store `PostAdMaxImage` it will update the first row and if I store `PostAdExpiredDay` it will update the second row

Comment: @madalinivascu I still get the same error

Comment: paste the `dd($postAdMaxImage)` here

Comment: @madalinivascu
{#362 ▼
  +"MembershipValue": "15"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157046/discussion-between-james-riady-and-madalinivascu).

Comment: update multi data with [updateBatch] (https://github.com/mavinoo/updateBatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values use the `value` function

```
$postAdMaxImage = DB::table('role_memberships')->wh‌​ere('role_id', $role->id)->where('MembershipName' , 'PostAdMaxImage')->value('MembershipValue');
$postAdExpiredDay = DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id', $id)->where('MembershipName' , 'PostAdExpiredDay')->value('MembershipValue');
```

change your view to:

```
  value="{{$postAdMaxImage}}"
  value="{{$postAdExpiredDay}}"
```

In the second question you need to alter your `update` function to update the fields not create new ones

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $PostAdMaxImage= $request['PostAdMaxImage'];
    $PostAdExpiredDay = $request['PostAdExpiredDay'];
    DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id',$id)->where('MembershipName','PostAdMaxImage')->update(['MembershipValue'=>$PostAdMaxImage]);
DB::table('role_memberships')->where('role_id',$id)->where('MembershipName','PostAdExpiredDay')->update(['MembershipValue'=>$PostAdExpiredDay]);


    return response()->json(array($role, $membership));
}
```